# How to exercise Tensorflow XLA AOT support in tensorflow's distribution

Tags: tensorflow

Tensorflow 1.0 has introduced XLA support that includes JIT compilation and AOT compilation. For JIT compilation, I found a python test script with which it can be unit-tested. However, I've not found any python test for AOT compilation. There are bazel tests though, which can be run on source tree.
Tensorflow's link https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/tfcompile provides information on how to test. But tfcompile does not make into the tensorflow's distribution content. I may be wrong here. But I could not see tfcompile anywhere in the TF's distribution directory where it is installed.
Could anyone please help me understand how to test AOT compilation on the existing distribution content OR I need to tweak something in the code to allow AOT stuff to go into distribution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The target for binary is `//tensorflow/compiler/aot:tfcompile` (I see reference in `tensorflow/compiler/aot/tfcompile.bzl`). You need to build this binary yourself, XLA is experimental and hence JIT/AOT bits are not included in official release

Comment: As you suggested I've //tensorflow/compiler/aot:tfcompile in tensorflow/tensorflow/tool/pip_package/BUILD in build_pip_package target. tfcompile stuff also builds and a binary is found in bazel-out directory. But this binary is not going into wheel file. Is there any change which I'm missing? This is how I've been adding additional stuff to my wheel file. But somehow, tfcompile is not working. Kindly help me.

Comment: That's probably by default -- since it's experimental, the script that puts things into Wheel file explicitly excludes it

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll check exactly where it excludes it explicitly from wheel file.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, could you please tell me where exactly it is getting excluded? I checked all the files inside tools/pip_package, but unable to find it.

Comment: Could anyone please help me to find out where exactly tfcompile is excluded from pip package? Or what do I need to do explcitly add it into pip package? I added above build target into tools/pip_package/BUILD file.

Comment: maybe you can make your own pip package just with tfcompile binary?

Comment: It is unbelievable how such an important feature of Tensorflow, no matter how experimental it is, gets no attention

Answer (score 0):

I know you're asking specifically about AOT, but I recommend you first read this page: https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/

And then read this one: https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/jit

In particular note that XLA is not included in our binary distributions; you **must** build from source at the moment.  Note that you must pick "enable XLA" when you run `./configure` in order for XLA support to be enabled.

Once you've done that, Yaroslav Bulatov's advice is correct; you can build the binaries yourself, or run the tests via bazel.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I've gone through those links earlier and understood that the support is experimental and can be enabled while ./configure. I'm sorry for not being clear earlier. I've built tensorflow myself enabling XLA support while configure and created a wheel file. So, by distribution, I meant the installed TF, whose .whl file is created by building the source. Despite of enabling XLA, nothing from tfcompile is seen in the installed location. Do we need to explicitly build this target in addition to enabling XLA? And other than bazel tests, are there any python tests for AOT testing?

Comment: AFAIK tfcompile is a standalone program and it's never included in the pip package, though it would be convenient to use AOT via the pip package (like a `tf.compile(graph)` function or something) if XLA is ever included in the PyPI release.